# Retrofit connects via Mobile Service because Wi-Fi network doesn't have Internet connection

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, android-networking

I have an app that have to connect to some device via Wi-Fi and send some data to it (local address `192.168.4.1`).

I have some Controller class for that purpose:

```
public class Controller {

private CallbackListener mListener;
private RestApiManager mApiManager;

public Controller(CallbackListener listener) {
    mApiManager = new RestApiManager();
    mListener = listener;
}

public void sendSomeData(String data) {

    SomeRestApi api = mApiManager.getSomeApi();

    api.sendDataToDevice(data, new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void success(String s, Response response) {
            mListener.onSuccess(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            mListener.onFailure(error);
        }
    });
}

public interface CallbackListener {
    void onSuccess(String response);
    void onFailure(RetrofitError error);
}
```

If my smartphone (Android M 6.0.1) is connected only to that Wi-Fi and Mobile service is off all goes okay: data is sending to the device as predicted. But the problem is, that device doesn't have the Internet connection, so if my phone has Mobile service on, Android choose that network as primary and Retrofit tries to send my data through that service, not wi-fi network, so I'm unable to connect to the local address.

Right now I check Active Network before sending data as following:

```
private boolean isActiveNetworkWifi() {

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        return activeNetworkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
}
```

And if Active network isn't `ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI` I simply ask user to turn off a mobile service.

I know that starting with Lollipop you have an option to somehow register your network calls to use such No-Internet Wi-Fi network along with Mobile service:

```
NetworkRequest.Builder request = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
request.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
```

But how can I use that in terms of using Retrofit controller?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Retrofit problem, but "intelligence" of Android since Lollipop which manages your request to use Internet-enabled connection instead empty one. In order to manage this issue you need to explicitly bind connection to particular network type. I have no idea how to solve it with Retrofit (I had same issue, but on Socket level), but here is an article which could give you more insights on how to solve it [Connecting your App to a Wi-Fi Device](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/connecting-your-app-to-wi-fi-device.html)